# Paypal process data to database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

For two days ive been trying to sort out the paypal payment function..
I have the purchases inserted into payments.db except for the userId wich needs to be copied from the users_test.db (current user logged in.)

Ive checked that  get the userId from the user logged in but im having trouble getting this inserted into the payments.db

I then need 'itemid' from payments.db inserted into column 'mmbrship' in users_test.db

Any suggestions?

```
    function updatePayments($data, $str){   
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){
      $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, userId, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
            '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
             '".$data['user_id']."' ,
              '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
            '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
            '".$data['item_number']."' ,
            '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'
            )", $link);



      $usersUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE users_test SET mmbrship = '" . $data['item_number'] . "' where user_id = '" . $data['$user_id'] . "';", $userUpdate);
     // $update = mysql_insert_id($userUpdate);

    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$usersUpdate = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` see if anything's up with the DB. Plus, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Plus, you are calling the `updatePayments()` function, right?

Comment: yes the function is being called. I get all the other values inserted to payments.db, just not the userid from users_test.db and nothing gets updated into users.db

Seems like nothing is up with the DB